# Ruby on Rails: Why can't I pass a variable to a mailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, arguments, actionmailer

In my Ruby on Rails application I am trying to send emails using the logged in user's email account, I am trying to do this by setting the SMTP settings in the mailer and passing the email address user name from my controller as follows:

Controller:

```
def create
    # Make a new email
    @email = Email.new(email_params)
    # For the email, store the user id as the id of the user logged in
    @email.user_id = session[:user_id]  
    # store the user id
    @user = session[:user_id]
    # if the email has saved in the database
    if @email.save
        email_to_name = @email.to_name
        # split the email addresses selected by the ";"
        @emails = (email_params[:to]).split("; ")
        # for each email address selected do the following
        @emails.each do |emailaddress|
            # the "to" section of the email is to one email address
            @email.to = emailaddress
            # find who to address the email to using the Contact model
            @email.to_name = address_email_to(email_to_name, @email.prefix, emailaddress)
            # find the contact the user wants to email
            contact = Contact.find_by_email(emailaddress).id
            # generate a unsubscribe token
            @unsubscribe = Rails.application.message_verifier(:unsubscribe).generate(contact)       
            # PASS THE ACCOUNT ID TO THE SMTP SETTINGS METHOD IN MY MAILER
            UserEmails.smtp_settings(@email.account_id)
            # send the email
            UserEmails.send_email(@email, @unsubscribe, @email.logo).deliver_now
        end
        # show the email
        redirect_to @email, notice: 'Email was successfully created.'
    # if not saved
    else
        # go back to the new email page
        redirect 'new'
    end
  end
```

Mailer:

```
class UserEmails < ApplicationMailer

    if Rails.env.development?
        class <<self
          def smtp_settings(account)
            options = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/mailers.yml")[Rails.env]['send_email']
            @@smtp_settings = {
              :address              => 'smtp.gmail.com',
              :port                 => 587,
              :domain               => 'my-domain.com',
              :authentication       => 'plain',
              # FIND THE USER-NAME IN THE ACCOUNT MODEL
              :user_name            => Account.find_by_id(account).email,
              :password             => 'my password', 
            }
          end
        end
    end

    def send_email(email, unsubscribe, logo)
        @url  = 'http://localhost:3000/users/login'
        @email = email
        @unsubscribe = unsubscribe
        @logo = logo
        mail(from: "#{@email.from_name} <#{@email.account.email}>", to: @email.to, cc: @email.cc, bcc: @email.bcc, subject: @email.subject, message: @email.message)
    end
end
```

So I'm trying to pass the account id from the controller to the mailer, but I get the error: `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)`

I understand that this means the `smtp_settings` is expecting to receive data and that the controller is not passing it, but I don't understand why when I have the line `UserEmails.smtp_settings(@email.account_id)`.

Can someone please help me figure this out?

Comment: Are you aware that using an email address that doesn't match up your smtp server's configuration makes is very likely that the email will end up in spam? Furthermore some smtp server will refuse to send emails without a proper sender address for exactly that reason.

Comment: I am only using the user-name as a test, if this works then I intend to also configure the other smtp settings for each user. E.g. the system stores an address, port, domain, authentication user-name, and password for each user, when user 1 sends an email these are all configured as per their settings, when user 2 sends an email these are configured as per their settings. I am only including user-name as a test at the minute to see if this theory would work.